# Algebraic notation - how to represent optional parameter in a function?

Tags: notation, programming

So for the academic paper I'm writing, I'm wondering if there is a specific notation for optional parameters in a general function equation.

[image: equation without optional parameter]

[image: equation with optional parameter]

These equations relate to Python v3.7 implementations where optional parameters are permitted.

(Not sure if this belongs in the correct exchange domain)

-- EDIT --

> A number of fitness value functions will be assessed on their ability to output desirable solutions against the requirements for arbitrary parameters in addition to the sample configuration model. All fitness functions follow the below format:

$$ fitV_j = f\left(\vec x_j, opt_1, ..., opt_n\right)
; n \ge 0 ; n \lt 10 ; n \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

Comment: If you [edit] the question to show us a sentence or two and surrounding the definition or equation you are trying to write we may be able to suggest appropriate notation. Just those images don't provide enough information. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I don't know the convention for academic papers in that subfield, but if these are directly related to optional arguments in Python, would it be reasonable to use Python notation instead of trying to allude to optional arguments in traditional mathematical notation which isn't really set up for that?

Comment: @MarkS. fair point. except the remainder of my problem definition is defined in algebra to be platform independent and also because this is how other authors describe their problems. If there isn't any formal notation for optional arguments this is okay, as I can just use my own :D